# Call/Return feature of classic C++(C with Classes), what modern languages have it?

Tags: c++, programming-languages, language-features, aop

On page 57 of [The Design and Evolution of C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201543303), Dr. Stroustrup talks about a feature that was initially part of C with Classes, but it isn't part of modern C++(standard C++). The feature is called `call/return`. This is an example:

```
class myclass
{
  call() { /* do something before each call to a function. */ }
  return() { /* do something else after each call to a function. */ }
  ...
};
```

I find this feature very interesting. Does any modern language have this particular feature?

Comment: Looks similar to AOP: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming

Comment: @gf That's interesting, I think I am going to take a look at some AOP framework for C++, because I have never done that before :)

Comment: This looks very aspect-oriented. I'm curious why this was considered and then dropped.
Also... I don't have that book so I have to ask: was this feature designed to apply before *any* function of the class, or before a *specific* function? Would it have been possible to define different `call()` s and `return()` s for different functions?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner Dr. Stroustrup said that it was removed because he was the only one who used that feature in "The Task Library' which he was writing, and he "completely failed" to convince people that it had an important use.

Comment: Too bad, it sounds like he was a bit ahead of the times with this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The modern C++ equivalent would be a sentry object: construct it at the beginning of a function, with its constructor implementing `call()`, and upon return (or abnormal exit), its destructor implements `return()`.

Comment: Are not sentry objects just for input and output streams ?

Comment: +1 Thanks, I didn't even know about this class in C++. Hopefully I'll try to implement my own!

Comment: @Romain: you can make sentry objects for anything you want. I use them frequently while debugging, and to ensure invariants are maintained. They're also frequently employed to help ensure functions are properly exception safe.

Comment: Sentry objects are very similar indeed. On the one hand they require explicit instantiation (and being passed `this`) but on the other hand you can add to them so that they check not only the invariants of the class but some pre/post conditions for the function at hand.

Comment: This is not really a language construct, but an idiom

Comment: @Romain: correct. When you implement it, though, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Aspect Oriented Programming has this.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming

Aspect Oriented Programming (also known as AOP) has the ability to create interceptors before, after and around code.

Answer (score 0):

The D2 programming language has this and more with it's [ScopeGuards](http://dlang.org/statement.html#ScopeGuardStatement). It's designed so you can use multiple ones, they work like a FILO stack.