# How to do Sentry pattern in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, design-patterns

In C++, I'm used to using the sentry pattern to ensure that resources acquired are properly released when the block or function exits (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690851/what-is-sentry-object-in-c) for example).  I used this, for example, for grabbing the graphics state, and then I can do whatever I want to that state, and it gets put back when the sentry object (reference) goes out of scope.

Now I'm using C#, and the same trick doesn't work, because the destructor doesn't get called until who-knows-when later.

Is there some OTHER method that is guaranteed to fire when an object's last reference is released?  Or do I just have to remember to call some Restore() or Apply() or DoYourThing() method before returning from any method where I would otherwise use a sentry?

Comment: "Is there some OTHER method that is guaranteed to fire when an object's last reference is released" No. :-(  I've lamented this too.  The .NET Dispose pattern is the best possible substitute.

Comment: I assume you've seen [Implementing RAII in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972763/implementing-raii-in-c-sharp) (maybe even duplicate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# provides the `using` block for this case, which works on any object that implements `IDisposable`.

For example, if you have a type `class Foo : IDisposable` then you can do this:

```
using (new Foo(/* ... */)) {
    // Your code that depends on this resource.
}
```

This is equivalent to:

```
Foo x = new Foo(/* ... */);
try {
    // Your code
} finally {
    if (x != null) {
        ((IDisposable)x).Dispose();
    }
}
```

Except, of course, that you don't have access to `x`.  You can, however, gain such access if you need it by creating a variable in the `using` block:

```
using (Foo foo = new Foo(/* ... */)) {
    // Your code that uses "foo"
}
```

The standard way of creating a class that can be disposed of this way *or* by the garbage collector is:

```
class Foo : IDisposable {
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        // Your cleanup code goes here.
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        Dispose(true);
    }

    ~Foo() {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, everyone!  You all had the right answer (and I feel like a dunce for not thinking of it myself, as I have used "using" elsewhere before).  But the pattern @cdhowie shows here is especially good to know about, so I'll mark this as the answer (and upvote everybody else to share the love).

Answer (score 12):

C# has finalizers, like C++, that are called when an object is destroyed. They are in the same form as C++, that is:

```
~ClassName()
{
}
```

As you know, though, C# does not have deterministic memory management, and so this isn't really a great guarantee. AS a direct result, you should *not* use finalizers for releasing unmanaged resources in C#. Instead, we use the `IDisposable` interface. This exposes a single method on the implementor, `Dispose`, which is intended to be called when you want to release unmanaged resources.

```
public class MyDisposable : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // get rid of some expensive unmanaged resource like a connection
    }
}
```

We can also use the `using` sugar to allow semantic invocation of `Dispose()` when the `using` block terminates (gracefully or not).

```
using(var disposable = new MyDisposable)
{
    // Do something with the disposable
} // Dispose is invoked here
```

Should you find yourself using finalizers *and* `Dispose`, you can consider using the `GC.SuppressFinalize` method, although that's a bit out of my scope. There was a really good discussion elsewhere on StackOverflow about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538060/proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface?lq=1)

This can be used to perform RAII-esque trickery, of course, such as

```
using(var guard = new Guard(resource))
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

To implement deterministic deallocation of unmanaged resources, you would use a Dispose pattern.  For many cases you can combine this with a `using` block if you want this to occur within a specific scope.

File handles or handles to a graphics device would usually be considered a unmanaged resource.  These are resources that the .NET framework does not track references for and does not automatically deallocate.

If it is managed resource, just references to C# objects/lists, then usually deterministic deallocation is not necessary, and the garbage collector can usually handle these more efficiently than you can.  **Don't worry so much about when managed resources are deallocated.**  If you no longer have a reference to them, then they should be of no concern.  The concern comes when you are done with something but somehow have a lingering reference to it that is preventing the GC from deallocating it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're describing is objects that implement the `IDisposable` interface for C#.  the IDisposable has a Dispose() method, that when defined properly on your own objects, is used to release resources.

Additionally C# does have destructors defined as such:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        // constructor
    }

    ~Foo() // destructor
}
```

when wrapping IDisposable objects in a using block, the Dispose() method is automatically called, the other option is to throw it in a finally block (when not using... using)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is enclosing the sentry object in a using statement.  So something like this.

```
using (sentry = new Sentry())
{
    //do your stuff here
}
```

After this block, sentry will have been released and out of scope.